# Labels on the QGIS WMS layers are not drawn according to the style definition

Tags: wms, labeling, qgis-2, qgis-server

I have an issue regarding the styling of labels of WMS layers using QGIS server. I can't seem to get them to display how I want.

What I did:

- create a QGIS project (2.2 on Mac) with a layer from a database
- style the layer, including the labels on QGIS desktop
- save project on the server (Ubuntu) to create the WMS

What I get:

- my WMS layer, nicely showing up
- except for the labels that seem to use a default symbolization, whatever the changes I make in the project (understand big black labels)

What I wished:

- control the size and maybe also the font of the labels.

Is there a nifty parameter that I forgot somewhere or is the labeling engine not working propoperly with WMS? Any hints or similar experiences welcome.

Comment: Did you resolve? I am facing the similar situation!

Comment: which version of QGIS are you using? I think this should not be an issue anymore.

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.18 and and then copying my project on the QGIS server directory.

Comment: I am working on ubuntu 17.10 operating  system.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the request of @Ahsan Mukhtar, I went to check again my latest project running on QGIS 2.14 (Windows Server):

Controlling the size, color, style and halo of the labels work.

On the previous settings I had (Ubuntun - QGIS 2.2), I cannot tell you anymore what happened.

My advice:

- check that the fonts you are using are also present on the server installation
- make sure you are creating your project in the same desktop version of QGIS as the one you are using for the server